# Using declaration (Derived class)

Tags: c++, derived-class, using-declaration

```
struct B1{
  int d;
  void fb(){};
};

struct B2 : B1{
  using B1::d;
  using B1::fb;

  int d;               // why this gives error?
  void fb(){}          // and this does not?
};

int main(){}
```

Is it because, `B1::fb()` is treated as `B1::fb(B1*)` `and B2::fb()` treated as `B2::fb(B2*)`? That is, does the implicit parameter, help in distinguishing these?

> $13.3.1/4-
>
> For nonconversion functions introduced
>   by a using-declaration into a derived
>   class, the function is considered to
>   be a member of the derived class for
>   the purpose of defining the type of
>   the implicit object parameter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The C++ standard (C++03 §7.3.3/12) explains:

> When a *using-declaration* brings names from a base class into a derived class scope, member functions in the derived class override and/or hide member functions with the same name and parameter types in a base class (rather than conflicting).

In your example, `B2::fb()` hides the `B1::fb()` introduced by the using declaration.

As for why it is ill-formed to have both `using B1::d;` and `int d;` in the definition of `B2`, the C++ standard (C++03 §7.3.3/10) explains:

> Since a *using-declaration* is a declaration, the restrictions on declarations of the same name in the same declarative region also apply to *using-declarations.*

So, it is ill-formed for the same reason that the following is ill-formed:  it results in two objects with the same name in a single declarative region:

```
struct S { int d; int d; };
```

Comment: what is the real impliciation of $13.3.1/4 in that case?

Comment: @chubsdad:  Since `B2::fb()` hides `B1::fb()`, `B1::fb()` is not considered as a candidate function during overload resolution, so §13.3.1/4 does not apply.