# why we use Using Declaration in derived class?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why shall I use the “using” keyword to access my base class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896830/why-shall-i-use-the-using-keyword-to-access-my-base-class-method)

`using` declaration introduces a name of data member or member function from a base class into the scope of derived class which is implicitly accomplished when we derive a class from base class, then what is the utility of using "using declaration"?

i want to know in depth the use of using declaration in classes in c++.

Comment: Could you add an example? I rarely use "using" in derived classes.

Comment: Show some code demonstrating the thing you're asking about.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544824/using-declaration-derived-class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896908/understanding-simple-c-inheritance/5896943#5896943 and http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/overcoming-name-shadowing-in-c/

Answer (score 4):

```
struct Base()
{
   void f(char);
};

struct Derived: Base
{
   void f(int);
};

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   d.f('a');
}
```

Which do you think will be called? It appears that `f(int)` is called, because the name f hides the name f in Base. So you need a using-declaration to enable it.

```
struct Derived: Base
{
   using Base::f;
   void f(int);
};
```

Now `f(char)` will be called.

That's one example. HTH